# Find an object with inheritance in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I have the database model as you can see in the screenshot below.

[image]

I want to display a Product in a page with the derived attributes (isbn if it's a book or pegi if it's a game for example). What is the best method to retrieve a Product from the web layer? Now I have a method `FindProduct(long productId)` that retrieves a product, but how can I get it's derived instance? (I have a `ProductDao`, `BookDao` and `GameDao`)Thanks.

```
public Product FindProduct(long productId)
{
    return ProductDao.Find(productId);
}
```

Comment: Can you please add screen show? Its not appeared.

Comment: By the way, always put same working code sample and code where you stuck. Otherwise community will downvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example shows how you can achive it in case of using `ASP.NET MVC/Core`
   If you don't want to use `dynamic`, than you can replace it on `is..as` chain.

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
  public ViewResult Product(long productId) 
  {
      var product = FindProduct(productId);
      var productView = GetRelevantProductView((dynamic)product);
      return productView; 
  }

  private void GetRelevantProductView(Book book)
  {
    return View("BookView", book);
  }

  private void GetRelevantProductView(Game game)
  {
    return View("GameView", game);
  }
```

}

Comment: `dynamic` works perfectly, that's what I was answering, thanks!